# How does one convert a question with a poor close reason to a better close reason?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, vote-to-close, closed-questions

This question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23453233/java-class-angular-bracket?noredirect=1#comment35957514_23453233

Is clearly a duplicate of this question:

[What does <> (angle brackets) mean in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6607550/what-does-angle-brackets-mean-in-java)

Marking it as a duplicate would clearly improve the site:  since the second question has 15 upvotes, it's clearly a useful question, and the first question might catch people who search for "angular bracket" rather than "angle brackets" and guide them to the right answer.

Unfortunately, despite only one close voter apparently specifying "off topic" as a reason to close, the first question has been closed as "off topic" rather than as a duplicate.

Is there a mechanism to convert such closed questions to "duplicate"?  How does a 3k rep user express the view that the question should be closed as a duplicate, but otherwise should not be closed?

Comment: Your best bet is chatting up enough high-rep users to do a complete open+reclose right cycle going. Only in special cicumstances is contacting a moderator with a custom flag the better way. Still, I doubt this one case will be corrected...

Comment: Just edit the question (or a comment) pointing to duplicate.

Comment: Nominated for reopening-then-immediately-closing. Who's with me?

Answer (score 4):

The duplicate close reason is meant for the cases, where the same problem can be expressed in multiple ways. The Google Search can lead the future visitor to both questions, but they will be then directed to the place where their question will be answered. This is the added value of duplicate questions.

In the linked case there's no added value for closing that as duplicate. If you remove heavy misspelling, you'd get the exact result on the google.

Under normal circumstances, if something is only duplicate, but is closed as not a duplicate, it can be easily reopened (since it's not a duplicate, and there's nothing wrong with the question, there's no reason for reviewers not to reopen). Then you can point out that it's a duplicate and get it closed again.

However, that particular question is so poor, that it should never be flagged for reopening. I can't imagine anyone conciously voting to reopen it.